# What is symmetry in physics in the mathematical sense, using (Lie) groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, symmetry

In physics, we sometimes say that, for example, a certain classical system has a certain symmetry, which is given by some group. I don't feel like I understand this well enough. Are there some good books you recommend to read that explain to me rigorously what symmetry means?  "What is symmetry?"  Where for example you have the Hamilton formalism (might even involve symplectic geometry) and how it points out toward a certain group and a certain action.  Perhaps might also have a link with representation theory. Searching for good books or papers. Thank you

Comment: This is a very popular topic with many good references (just google). My first google hit is [this one](http://wfa.uz.zgora.pl/images/jorjadze-lecture2.pdf), which is already quite nice.

Comment: Do you perhaps know something where you can see a good link with some classical system (hamilton formalism/ symplectic geometry)  and group symmetry?

Comment: Yes, google "the symplectic group as the group of phase space linear canonical transformations in Hamiltonian mechanics." My first hit is a book called "Hamiltonian Mechanics and Geometry". Seems not bad.